# How do you pick up money from traders in a settlement?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a traders stall in my settlement. Do I get the caps from him automatically or do I have to pick it up from somewhere? I can't seem to figure out if I've received any caps or not yet.

Answer (score 1):

The money will appear in the settlement workshop some people claim that the more people you have not assigned to anything the faster you make money but still haven't been able to confirm that even though I have been looking for a couple days.